# Inserting and Finding a Node Structure

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm a bit confused because the code for inserting a code is:

```
public Node insert(Node root, int data) {

    // if tree is empty, create it and return 
    if(root == null) 
        return root = new Node(data);

    // recursively insert new node
    if(data < root.data) 
        root.left = insert(root.left, data);

    else if(data > root.data)
        root.right = insert(root.right, data);

    return root;

}
```

and finding a node is:

```
public Node find(Node root, int data) {

    if(root == null) 
        return null;

    if(root.data == data) {
        System.out.println(root.data + " found");
        return root;
    }


    if(data < root.data) 
        return find(root.left, data);
    else if(data > root.data)
        return find(root.right, data);

    return root;
}
```

Can't you use `root.left = find(root.left, data)` and `root.right = find(root.right, data)` in the find method instead of `return find(root.left, data)` and `return find(root.right, data)`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution you suggest, you are assigning values to root.left and root.right, which would change the tree, something you definetly do not want in a find method (which should leave the tree untouched). Returning the node simply looks for it recursively, and returns it.

The main difference is when you insert, you do want to change the tree, that is, add the new node in its proper place. When you want to find a node in the tree, you do not want to make any assignations, just return the node you are looking for.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. I appreciate the wisdom!